# dotnet core 6 identity injection have usermanager is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a code to use `UserManager` like this:

```cs
var userWithSameUserName = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
```

in my AccountService.cs

```cs
public AccountService(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IOptions<JWTSettings> jwtSettings,
            IDateTimeService dateTimeService,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _jwtSettings = jwtSettings.Value;
            _dateTimeService = dateTimeService;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            this._emailService = emailService;
        }
```

I try to re create https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi from scratch to use dotnetcore 6

this code in `infrastructure.identity`

and in `ServiceRegistration` I already add

```cs
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityContext).Assembly.FullName)));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            #region Services
            services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            #endregion
```

I also already add to `program.cs` in my WebApi Project

```cs
using Application;
using Application.Interfaces;
using Infrastructure.Identity;
using Infrastructure.Persistence;
using Infrastructure.Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Readbuk.Api.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddApplication();

builder.Services.AddIdentityInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddPersistenceInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticatedUserService, AuthenticatedUserService>();

#region API Versioning
// Add API Versioning to the Project
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    // Specify the default API Version as 1.0
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    // If the client hasn't specified the API version in the request, use the default API version number 
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    // Advertise the API versions supported for the particular endpoint
    config.ReportApiVersions = true;
});
#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        //await DefaultRoles.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
        //await DefaultBasicUser.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
        //await DefaultSuperAdmin.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
    }
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

but when I debug it, the `_userManager` in `AccountService.cs` is null

where I wrong so the injection not run well

Comment: If you try to change the service lifetime,will it be solved?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou how to change the service lifetime?